# Android ListView remember previous selected item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `ListView` populated by a `String array`. The user select one item  and it background color changes. Now, the user clicks `back button` in mobile and goes back to `mainActivity` and again return to `listviewActivity`. The selected item is not shown anymore in the `listView`.

Comment: use shared preference

Comment: save last selected item position and check

Comment: If the state is not important or if you are careful to persist it, keeping the selection in memory is the fastest solution. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Comment: Suppose this list may change. When you go back, you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the index of the selected list item using [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) and retrieve it back on the `onCreate` callback. Or you can also use [Room persistence](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/) to store the index to the database and retrieve in the `onCreate` callback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `String[]` to `ArrayList` with two new items along with String value you have populate in `Listview`

first need to make one Bean Class

```
class Data{

private String colourName;
private String colourCode;//int colourCode
private boolean ;

//make setter and getter methods
}
```

make

```
List<Data> colourDataList =new  ArrayList<Data>();
```

use above `List` with `Adapter` ,

update `boolean` flag value to true when it selected.

save Data Beans to any storage in `Android` , like

```
SQLite

SharedPresence

local File
```

Next when you load data to same adapter take value from local database and map with your new data and set to `ListView` Item, like `colourCode` as par `boolean` `flag` `value (true)`.